# Eliminate rows with a particular factor level

Tags: r

I have a factor with a great many levels and would like to eliminate 2 of them. I know that I could use subset to extract particular levels of a factor to form a new dataset. Since I have many levels, I would like to eliminate particular levels instead, however.

In the following example, how do I eliminate the fish level?

```
catsDogsFish=c(rep("cat", 5), rep("dog", 5), rep("fish", 5))
happyInside=c(7,4,9,7,8, 2,4,7,3,3,9,8,9,10,10)
happyPets=data.frame(catsDogsFish, happyInside)
```

Comment: Why can't you use `subset`?

Comment: You can do `happyPets[happyPets$catsDogsFish != "fish", ]`

Comment: Is it possible to use subset to create a dataframe without rows of a particular factor level?

Comment: Or, if `catsDogsFish` doesn't exist outside of your data frame: `happyPets[happyPets$catsDogsFish != "fish", ]`

Comment: Or if this is a toy example and you ahd more levels to drop, you could expand on @AndrewGustar's answer with `happyPets[!(catsDogsFish %in% c("fish", "dog")), ]`

Comment: If you want to use `subset`, then `notFish <- subset(happyPets, !(catsDogsFish %in% c("fish")))`

Comment: Thank you all, I will try these suggestions out! Thanks!

Comment: You have to assign the result. If you have `x = 1`, then `x + 1` will print `2`, but the value of `x` is still `1` If you want to change x to 2, you need to do `x = x + 1`. This is the same for your data. `happyPets[catsDogsFish != "fish", ]` will print the data frame without the fish rows, but if you want to change the original data you need to assign the result with `=` or `<-`: `happyPets = happyPets[catsDogsFish != "fish", ]`.

Comment: I have additional question: I have never seen "%in%" used. It tells R to look inside a variable at a particular level? Why is "in" surrounded by two % ?